# VS Code jumps to source instead of build

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm working on a huge repo containing multiple workspaces with projects written in typescript.

With Yarn I manage all of these workspaces and install them into each other.

Now the Problem is the following:

Since one workspace is installed into another workspace, i'm not able to jump to source anymore. VS Code jumps into the build directory instead regardless of the existence of a map or not.

Am I somehow able to tell VS Code that it has to jump into the source directory of packages instead of the build directory?